# how to transfer files between two ftps

Tags: ftp

I need to transfer files from my ftp to another, is there any tool to put two access and I transfer from one to another without downloading the files to my machine?

Comment: If you have shell access you can SSH into serverA and then do an FTP from serverA to serverB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a client that supports the FXP protocol, as described in one of the answers from this webmaster.stackexchange.com Q&A: [How can I transfer files from one server to another server using FTP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-one-server-to-another-server-using-ftp)

The following is from the [SmartFTP Knowledge base](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/what-is-fxp-f14.html):

*excerpt*

> #### What Is FXP?
>
> FXP stands for File eXchange Protocol. It lets you copy files from one
>   FTP-server to another using an FXP-client. Normally you transfer files
>   using the FTP protocol between your machine and a FTP-server, and the
>   maximum transfer speed depends on the speed of your Internet
>   connection (e.g. 56k, cable or T1). When transferring files between
>   two remote servers using an FXP client, the maximum transfer speed
>   does not depend on your connection but only on the connection between
>   the two servers, which is usually much faster than your own
>   connection. Because it is a direct connection you will not be able to
>   see the progress or the transfer speed of the files.

2 such clients that support this are [SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/what-is-fxp-f14.html) and [CuteFTP](http://www.cuteftp.com/cuteftp/).

*excerpt*

> #### Restrictions
>
> - Both FTP servers must support FXP and have it enabled. Please consult with the server administrator since most FTP servers do not
>     support FXP, or have FXP disabled due to potential security risks.
> - One server has to support PASV mode and the other server must allow PORT commands from a foreign address. The client logs in to both
>     servers and then it arranges for a file transfer by telling one server
>     that it will be a passive transfer and the other that it will be an
>     active transfer, see example.

*excerpt*

> #### Example
>
> The FTP client tells the destination FTP server to listen for a
>   connection by sending a "PASV" command. The source FTP server connects
>   to the data port reported by the destination server (after a
>   successful PASV command). The client then passes the address/port in a
>   "PORT" command to the destination server. Thus all the data goes
>   directly from the source to the destination FTP server. Both servers
>   only report status messages on fail/success to the FTP client. You can
>   transfer files from one remote server to another using SmartFTP by
>   opening a remote server in each window and then dragging and dropping.

#### References

- [Knowledge Base - Home > What is ... > What Is FXP?](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/what-is-fxp-f14.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FXP. I use CBFTP for Linux FXP: https://cbftp.eu/